# Add custom fields to CometD subscribe message

Tags: java, android, cometd, bayeux

I am using CometD Java client on Android.

> compile group: 'org.cometd.java', name: 'cometd-java-client', version:
>   '2.9.1'

I need to subscribe to a channel on a CometD server. But there is a problem - the server requires a custom subscribe message (this is the expected subscribe message payload from the server docs):

```
[
    {
        "user": "xyz-WQUAq3shWho1ZcJHaibQYzCh2ILMMX1o-gA6NuehTFYMhvViv6Ow3dvPbyt8Zwg10-bd8bd779f107615b1c5a1470706e4050e5389ddc",
        "domain": "xyz",
        "pid": "gA6NuehTFYMhvViv6Ow3dvPbyt8Zwg10",
        "sid": "85f103a2",
        "gid": "WQUAq3shWho1ZcJHaibQYzCh2ILMMX1o",
        "pageId": "6ea23e",
        "entityId": "xyz",
        "triggeringGoal": "3E955818355C44E2479B2A26629E69566C8C6376",
        "chatSearchPattern": "ua.domain=xyz",
        "startTime": 1482931626853,
        "metadata": "{}",
        "chatMetadata": "{}",
        "language": "en",

        "id": "3",
        "channel": "\/meta\/subscribe",
        "subscription": "\/chat\/xyz-WQUAq3shWho1ZcJHaibQYzCh2ILMMX1o-gA6NuehTFYMhvViv6Ow3dvPbyt8Zwg10-bd8bd779f107615b1c5a1470706e4050e5389ddc",
        "clientId": "26l1v2ngpdcwdtno1wu30rk92dur4",
        "ext": {
        }
    }
]
```

So my question is how do I add custom fields to the subscribe message (`user`, `domain`, `pid`, `sid` etc)? Currently I am subscribing to channels like this:

```
cometdClient.getChannel("/chat/" + clientID).subscribe(new ChannelListener("/chat/ messages"), new ChannelListener("/chat/ progress"));
```

But it is failing as expected.

By the way I am using `org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient` as the HttpClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should really upgrade as CometD 2.9.1 is really old now, and JDK 7 is supported on Android.

The design of the server requiring all those fields in a `/meta/subscribe` message is really wrong.
Most of that information is static (e.g. `user` and various "cookies" such as `pid` etc.) and can be determined at the time of the CometD handshake, so there is no need to send it over during a subscription.

Also, sending it during a `/meta/subscribe` message makes it subject to attacks (an attacker can forge a message with a different `user` field, for example). You want to read the [security section](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_security) of the [CometD documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/).

Furthermore, using a channel per user (as it appears that the channel name is a concatenation of `/chat/` and the `user` field) is not a recommended approach, since it will create possibly a lot of channels, while the same functionality can be achieved much more efficiently with a single service channel (and the `user` as a field of the messages being sent).

If you really have to add those fields to the `/meta/subscribe` message, the way to do it is to use a [custom extension](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_extensions), along these lines:

```java
class SubscribeExtension extends ClientSession.Extension.Adapter {
    @Override
    public boolean sendMeta(ClientSession session, Message.Mutable message) {
        if (Channel.META_SUBSCRIBE.equals(message.getChannel())) {
            String subscription = (String)message.get(Message.SUBSCRIPTION_FIELD);
            if (subscription.startsWith("/chat/") {
                // Add fields.
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, if you really need to add extra fields to a `/meta/subscribe` message, you want to do it inside the `ext` field, with proper namespacing:

```json
{
    "id": "3",
    "channel": "/meta/subscribe",
    "subscription": "/chat/xyz-WQUAq3shWho1ZcJHaibQYzCh2ILMMX1o-gA6NuehTFYMhvViv6Ow3dvPbyt8Zwg10-bd8bd779f107615b1c5a1470706e4050e5389ddc",
    "clientId": "26l1v2ngpdcwdtno1wu30rk92dur4",
    "ext": {
        "com.acme.myapp": {
            "time": 1234567890,
            "pageId": "6ea23e",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the extra fields do no pollute the message itself, but are grouped in the `ext` field under namespace `com.acme.app` which would represent your company and application.

Comment: Thanks for pointing other things out too. Unfortunately I can't upgrade. Everything above 2.9.1 will fail during handshake with the exception: exception=java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.newSSLEngine(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: The `NullPointerException` has nothing to do with the CometD versions, it's probably just some bad configuration or missing calls to `start()` methods to start the lifecycle of those Jetty objects.